# Passing a string as an argument of a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am writing to write a function that searchs for varName in a file named fileName and return the line after. Altought I haven't finished writing I get

```
Error using searchDat (line 10)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Whenever trying to run the following code.

```
function [value] = searchDat(varName,fileName)
% Search 'varName' in the fileName
% Returns the line after
    fileID = fopen('input.dat','r');
    ii = 1;
    f = 0;
    while ~feof(fileID) 
        tline = fgetl(fileID) 
        if  strcmp(tline,varName)
            f = 1
        end
    end
    fclose(fileID);
end
```

Am I passing and using the strings as arguments properly?

Comment: How are you running the code? Are you hitting `F5` or are you calling it from the command line?

Comment: You need 2 input argumetts, remember, `searchDat('banana','tree.dat')`. Also, you are not opening that fileName, you always open `input.dat`